# String to hex value of FF in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking, twisted

I know this is a basic question, but I am really struggling to work it out.

I am trying to get a string to convert to FF in hex (i.e. OxFF) in python 2.7.

I convert the string to bytearray then to hex using the following code:

```
>>> data = 'OxFF'
>>> array = bytearray(data)
>>> print binascii.hexlify(array)
4f784646
```

For context, I am sending a message over TCP/IP using twisted and the header needs to be FF FF

Any help would be amazing.

Cheers

Comment: The conventional way to represent a hex byte is with "zero ex" not "big-oh ex" in front of the value. The Python 2 representation `'\xff'` is a single byte whose decimal value is 255. Is that the end result you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create directly the header as a string literal:

```
>>> header = '\xff\xff'
>>> hedaer
'\xff\xff'
```

Converting from `data`:

```
>>> data = '0xFF'
>>> binascii.unhexlify(data[2:])
'\xff'
```

The key is to skip over the `0x` prefix.

Or as an integer:

```
>>> int(data, 16)
255
```

where 255 is 0xFF of course.

Comment: I recommend avoiding bare string literals.  Even when they're not ambiguous (the question is tagged Python 2.7 so you can correctly say what this means) they can still lead to confusion, particularly for beginners.  In this case, `b'\xff\xff'` and `b'0xFF'` (though Python 2.7 hexlify/unhexlify take either bytes or unicode, they always return bytes; this seems like a hint that they really want to be operating on bytes to me (an explicit answer in the docs would be better, of course, but there is none I can see)).